# How do I highlight a grid row on hover and make it selected on click in Bootstrap?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, blazor, bootstrap-grid

I am loading data to a grid with 3 columns in Blazor. For the grid structure I have used Bootstrap rows and columns. If I need to highlight rows on hover and keep the row selected using onClick event what is the best way to achieve it?

Below is how I populate data.

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col">User Name</div>
        <div class="col">First Name</div>
        <div class="col">Last Name</div>
    </div>

    @foreach (var user in users)
    {
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col">@user.UserName</div>
            <div class="col">@user.FirstName</div>
            <div class="col">@user.LastName</div>
        </div>
    }
</div>
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to maintain the rows selected state.
Here is a generic view model to wrap any row type:

```
public class RowState<TItem>
{
    public RowState(TItem item) => Item = item;
    public TItem Item { get; set; }
    public bool IsSelected { get; set; }
}
```

Then using style classes for both selected and hover:

```
.hover-row:hover {
    background-color: #0000ff33;
}

.selected-row {
    background-color: #0000ff77;
}
```

I seperated the row into its own component `UserRow.razor` with a `[Parameter]` that takes the `RowState<User>` viewmodel.

This simplifies the logic to handle the click event and logic for the css class to highlight the row.

`UserRow.razor`

```
<div class="row hover-row @CssClass" @onclick="RowClicked" >
    <div class="col">@User.UserName</div>
    <div class="col">@User.FirstName</div>
    <div class="col">@User.LastName</div>
</div>

@code {
    [Parameter]
    public RowState<User> UserRowState { get; set; }   

    private void RowClicked() => UserRowState.IsSelected = !UserRowState.IsSelected;

    private User User => UserRowState.Item;
    private bool IsSelected => UserRowState.IsSelected;
    private string CssClass => IsSelected ? "selected-row" : "";
}
```

Refactoring your original code:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col">User Name</div>
        <div class="col">First Name</div>
        <div class="col">Last Name</div>
    </div>

    @foreach (var user in UserRows)
    {
        <UserRow UserRowState=user />     
    }
</div>

@code {
    IEnumerable<RowState<User>> UserRows = User.DemoData
        .Select(user => new RowState<User>(user))
        .ToList();
}
```

Here is a working [REPL](https://blazorrepl.com/repl/clktlKPQ35vR2wpn03)

Comment: Thank you @BrianParker that worked well for me.

Comment: I was using the onmouseover and onmouse out method. however whenever you crossed table grid lines this would cause the event to re-fire. by using css instead mentioned here on the tr property this removed that behaviour and solved this issue.

Answer (score 2):

```
<table class="table table-hover">
<tr>
    <td >User Name</td>
    <td >First Name</td>
    <td >Last Name</td>
</tr>

@foreach (var user in users)
{
    string bg = (user.Id == selectedUserId)? "bg-info" : "";
    <tr class=@bg @onclick=@SelectUser(user.Id) @key=user>
        <td >@user.UserName</td>
        <td >@user.FirstName</td>
        <td >@user.LastName</td>
    </tr>
}
```

```
@code{

  private int selectedUserId {get;set;} = 0;
  private void SelectUser(int userId){
   selectedUserId = userId;
  }

}
```

Comment: Code only answers go against community standards.

Comment: please tell me the problem, I want to learn.

Comment: We all want to learn, that is the problem. You are supposed to explain *how* this answer solves the problem, and link to supporting documentation where it is appropriate so that others may learn from it.  I personally do not know anything about Blazor, and this teaches me nothing.

Comment: Dear friend, it is really surprising that when you have no information about something you try to guide others. I think it is better for others to judge our answers.

Comment: @AliBorjian Thank you for your answer. However, you are using the table structure which I am not using in my question. Also it is something that I am moving away and will not suit the style of my responsive application.

Comment: Yes, this is answer is perfectly fine if you only want to select a single user.  @ZionSaver, it doesn't matter whether the answer uses a table; that's just formatting, it has nothing to do with how to select a row.  You can use a div, a span, a table row, a paragraph-- whatever you want.

Answer (score 0):

None of the JavaScript answers is appropriate for Blazor.  Ignore them.

If you just want **to select a single row**, you can use @Ali Borjian's answer

In order to track selection of multiple rows, you can use one of two methods:

1. **Use a class that tracks state information per row.**  This is Brian's answer.
2. **Create a secondary list that tracks which rows are selected.**  This follows.

.

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col">User ID</div>
        <div class="col">User Name</div>
    </div>

    @foreach (var user in Users)
    {
        string CSS = SelectedUsers.Contains(user) ? " Selected" : "";
        <div class="row @CSS" style="" @onclick="()=>ToggleSelection(user)">
            <div class="col">@user.ID</div>
            <div class="col">@user.Name</div>
        </div>
    }
</div>

@code {
    class User { public int ID; public string Name;  }

    List<User> Users = new List<User> { new User { ID = 1, Name = "Benjamin" }, new User { ID = 2, Name = "John" }, new User { ID = 3, Name = "David" } };
    List<User> SelectedUsers = new();

    void ToggleSelection(User user)
    {
        if (SelectedUsers.Any(u => u == user)) SelectedUsers.Remove(user);
        else SelectedUsers.Add(user);
    }

}
<style>
    .row {cursor:pointer}
    .row:hover { background-color:#c2d8ff }
    .Selected {background-color: #4781e9}
    .Selected:hover {background-color: #83aefb}
</style>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can utilize [Radio toggle buttons](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/forms/checks-radios/#radio-toggle-buttons) (for single selection) or [Checkbox toggle buttons](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/forms/checks-radios/#checkbox-toggle-buttons) (for multiple) as [Block buttons](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/buttons/#block-buttons) with just a little bit of custom styling. Put the whole user row inside the label and use the username or other unique field for the input id.

Here is an example using Radio toggle buttons:

```css
label.btn {
  border: none;
  border-radius: 0;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-F3w7mX95PdgyTmZZMECAngseQB83DfGTowi0iMjiWaeVhAn4FJkqJByhZMI3AhiU" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-4">User Name</div>
    <div class="col-4">First Name</div>
    <div class="col-4">Last Name</div>
  </div>

  <div class="row">
    <!-- @foreach (var user in users)
    { -->
    <div class="col-12 d-grid p-0">
      <input type="radio" class="btn-check" name="options" id="@user.UserName" autocomplete="off">
      <label class="btn btn-outline-dark text-start" for="@user.UserName">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-4">@user.UserName</div>
          <div class="col-4">@user.FirstName</div>
          <div class="col-4">@user.LastName</div>
        </div>
      </label>
    </div>
    <!-- } -->

    <div class="col-12 d-grid p-0">
      <input type="radio" class="btn-check" name="options" id="@user.UserName2" autocomplete="off">
      <label class="btn btn-outline-dark text-start" for="@user.UserName2">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-4">@user.UserName2</div>
          <div class="col-4">@user.FirstName</div>
          <div class="col-4">@user.LastName</div>
        </div>
      </label>
    </div>
    <div class="col-12 d-grid p-0">
      <input type="radio" class="btn-check" name="options" id="@user.UserName3" autocomplete="off">
      <label class="btn btn-outline-dark text-start" for="@user.UserName3">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-4">@user.UserName3</div>
          <div class="col-4">@user.FirstName</div>
          <div class="col-4">@user.LastName</div>
        </div>
      </label>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Javasccript in Blazor? :o

Comment: It's the bootstrap.js, You don't use it?

Comment: @AliBorjian sorry thought you were the OP for a second, the question asks how to do it in *Bootstrap*, this is a valid Boostrap solution.

Comment: he asked "I am loading data to a grid with 3 columns in Blazor."

Comment: @AliBorjian, I actually did not need the JavaScript (removed from snippet) works with just CSS.

Comment: No, he asked "How do I ... in Bootstrap?"

Comment: by the way you can not mange the selected row in Blazor only by CSS

Comment: Since maybe the #1 feature of Blazor is that you DON'T use Javascript unless absolutely necessary, then this answer isn't preferred.